# how to get records having value in column1 less than column2 using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a price table that contains columns **buy_price** and **sell_price**. Now, I want to get records that contains `buy_price < sell_price` using hibernate.

Just like a mysql query

```
select * from price where buy_price < sell_price;
```

but don't know how to perform using hibernate (CriteriaSpecification) as I am new to hibernate.

Comment: your JPA query will be almost same as the sql query you mentioned above. Give it a try and update the question if you face any problem.

Comment: @gagansingh with JPQL it is simple and simple to the native query, but with the criteria API it is not the same, and that's what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an entity called `Price` with attributes `buyPrice` and `sellPrice`.

Then `select * from price where buy_price < sell_price;` can be translated in [hibernate criteria query](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm) as (assuming you already have a hibernate session object):

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Price.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.lt("buyPrice", "sellPrice"));
List results = cr.list();
```

Comment: Not worked for my case. `Restrictions.lt("buyPrice", "sellPrice")` gives me `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` Because it expects value in this format : Restrictions.lt("columnName",value)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
    CriteriaQuery<Price> cq = cb.createQuery(Price.class);
    Root<Price> eg = cq.from(Price.class);
    cq.where(cb.gt(eg.get("sellPrice"), eg.get("buyPrice")));
```

Comment: thanks for answer but I want to make such a query using CriteriaSpecification such as Restrictions.lt

Comment: This answer uses JPA, which is a standard and hibernate is the reference implementation of the same. Anyway it is your choice. If you try, please put a comment here saying whether this worked or not. You may still use hibernate restrictions but atleast it would be nice to know whether this worked. I do not have the env to try this out.